# Using WhirlyGlobe-Maply with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, import, swift, frameworks

Im trying to use the binary library from WhirlyGlobe-Maply in one of my new projects.
The library can be found here: http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/

I'm not sure how to to proceed with it because the library is written in OBJ-C and I'm coding in swift. I know you need a bridging header, but as this is a framework, could somebody perhaps explain to me how to bridge this? What do I need to import in this header to make it work?

Regards,

Ron

Answer (score 2):

One of my users is putting together a Swift project.  You can look at that for a start.

https://github.com/jcollas/WhirlyGlobeSwift

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing me to it. I had seen it indeed but was not really clear on how to use it. Is it standalone, or is it an addition to your framework? And which headers to import from this module. The documentation is somewhat lacking.

Comment: It's an experiment, so no documentation to speak of.  It uses Cocoapods, so you need to set that up an then it just builds.

Comment: Just to update this, WhirlyGlobe-Maply 2.4.1 has explicit Swift support.